# Integrate $f(x, y) = \frac{\ln(x^2 + y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ over the region $1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le e^3$. Region not bounded with respect to $\theta$?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Integrate $f(x, y) = \dfrac{\ln(x^2 + y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$ over the region $1 \le x^2 + y^2 \le e^3$.

We change our coordinates system to simplify this computation:

$\therefore 1 \le \rho^2\cos^2\theta + \rho\sin^2\theta \le e^3$

$\implies 1 \le \rho^2 \le e^3$

$\implies 1 \le \rho \le e^{3/2}$ since $\rho \ge 0$

So we can find the bounds of integration in terms of $\rho$. But it seems that it is not possible to find the bounds of integration with respect to $\theta$? Does this mean that the region is not bounded with respect to $\theta$? What is the correct way to conceptually understand/interpret this?

I would greatly appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: isnt theta always between 0 and 2*pi?

Comment: This is because it's a complete circle...So what are the minimum and maximum $\theta$ that describe a circle?

Comment: @Abdel It depends on the region that we are integrating over. For instance, we could have a region $\dfrac{\pi}{2} \ge \theta \ge 0$.

Comment: @Triatticus But the algebra does not reveal any bounds for $\theta$. Shouldn't we have some algebraic indication of what $\theta$ should be?

Comment: I think you should just do the integration. Then you will see that by using the jocobian, the integral simplifys in this new coordinate system. I think you are left to integrate ln(p^2).

Comment: Yes it does reveal bounds...By not being specified theta must assume it's maximum range since only the radius is bounded by two constant radii. In other words you have two circles and the area between them, since they make closed circles theta must lie in $[0, 2\pi)

Comment: @Triatticus Ok, that was my question. So since $\theta$ is not bounded by the bounds of integration for our region, this indicates that it is unbounded on the region (it implicitly indicates $2\pi > \theta \ge 0$)?

Comment: More or less though I think a better word is unspecified

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bounds of the integration are revealed by the geometry of the domain of integration. Your region is an annulus and so it is described in polar coordinates by

$$ 1 \leq \rho \leq e^{\frac{3}{2}}, \,\, 0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi. $$

By changing the coordinates to polar coordinates, you are left with computing

$$ \int_0^{e^{\frac{3}{2}}} \int_0^{2\pi} \ln(\rho^2) \, d \rho \,d \theta. $$

Comment: Thanks for the response. So since $\theta$ is not bounded by the bounds of integration for our region, this indicates that it is unbounded on the region (it implicitly indicates $2\pi > \theta \ge 0$)?

Comment: @ThePointer: Yeah, but I wouldn't say "it implicitly indicates". It is better to understand the geometry of the domain and then deduce the bounds instead of relying on plugging $x = \rho \cos \theta$, etc into the equation and see what happens. In your case, the region is an annulus which is a union of concentric circles around the origin so it is clear that $\theta$ should run from $0$ to $2\pi$ all along. This will often save you some time and help you avoid mistakes.

Comment: You have been very helpful. Thank you for the assistance.